# &lt; issue in AXIOM parser

Tags: xml-parsing, axiom

Axiom parser converts "&lt ;" to "<" if it is followed by empty node.This makes the xml content invalid.

XML Input:

```
case 1: <A> test <B></B> &lt; test1 </A>
case 2: <A> test <B>ear</B> &lt; test1 </A>
```

XML Output:

```
case 1: <A> test <B/> < test1 </A> [Incorrect]
case 2: <A> test <B>ear</B> &lt; test1 </A> [Correct]
```

Axiom Code:

```
InputStream ina = new FileInputStream(fileName);
OMElement root = OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(ina).getDocumentElement();
```

Is there any way to handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

This is [AXIOM-509](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIOM-509). A fix for that issue was released in Axiom 1.4.0.